# How to insert a value in a field Text using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't insert a value in field text in  html formulary using Selenium Python:

I have this HTML:

```
<div data-react-toolbox="input" class="_2dBwA"><input type="text" placeholder="Endereço de e-mail" class="_2WvFs" role="input"><span class="fT1WI"></span></div>
```

and this XPath:

```
(Copy Xpath) //*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input
```

and this:

```
(Copy outerHTML) <input type="text" placeholder="Endereço de e-mail" class="_2WvFs" role="input">
```

I did it, but dont worked:

```
[In]: login_name = 'Cassandra'
[In]: insert_login_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="root"]')
[In]: insert_login_name.send_keys(login_name);

[Out]: NoSuchElementException:  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id="root"]"}
```

After entering the text in this text field, the result would be in html 'values' = 'Cassandra'

```
<div data-react-toolbox="input" class="_2dBwA"><input type="text" placeholder="Endereço de e-mail" class="_2WvFs _3QmiH" role="input" value='Cassandra'><span class="fT1WI"></span></div>
```

What can i do? I'm new in that. Thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: selenium is unable to find the element at the given xpath. I suggest using `find_element_by_id('root')` instead of trying to use an xpath.

Comment: Don't work. insert_login_name = driver.find_elements_by_id("root") and after i do it insert_login_name.send_keys('Cassandra'); THE RESULT was AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: Check if there any iframe present above the input element.It seems like an iframe there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [desired element](https://www.atlasgov.com/login) is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element so to send a *character sequence* with in the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-react-toolbox='input']>input[placeholder='Endereço de e-mail'][type='text']"))).send_keys(login_name)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-react-toolbox='input']/input[@placeholder='Endereço de e-mail' and @type='text']"))).send_keys(login_name)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

Seems it was a locale issue. Changing the *value* of `placeholder` attribute from `Endereço de e-mail` to `E-mail address` works perfecto.

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-react-toolbox='input']>input[placeholder*='mail'][type='text']"))).send_keys(login_name)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-react-toolbox='input']/input[contains(@placeholder, 'mail') and @type='text']"))).send_keys(login_name)
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: @Gizélly Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: it works after update xpath! Thanks,i don't understand yesterday, but today i'm understand your work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.atlasgov.com/login")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[data-react-toolbox="input"] >input[placeholder="E-mail address"][role="input"]'))).send_keys("Cassandra")
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

---

> Updated Xpath.

---

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@data-react-toolbox="input" and @class="_2dBwA"]/input[@role="input"]'))).send_keys("Cassandra")
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[@data-react-toolbox="input"]//input[@role="input"])[1]'))).send_keys("Cassandra")
```

Comment: Don't work.. TimeoutException: Message: -------TimeoutException                          T

Comment: The link you have provided it is working in UK location.wait I will provide you another solution.

Comment: @Gizélly : Try updated xpath and let me know the status?

Comment: I have updated another xpath.use that one.That is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: selenium is unable to find the element at the given xpath. Since you have the element's id just use it directly instead of an xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('root')
```

Comment: Don't work. insert_login_name = driver.find_elements_by_id("root") and after i do it insert_login_name.send_keys('Cassandra'); THE RESULT was AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys' –

Comment: @Gizélly Double check what you typed. It isn't the same as what I put in my answer here.

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_id("root") returns '[]'

Comment: @Gizélly There are two issues. 1. `find_elements...` returns a **list** of elements, not a single element. This is why you get the error. You can change this to `find_element...` instead, but then you will get the same error message as before that the element is not found. 2. There is no element with an id of `root`. This is probably related to your original error. You need to find the correct selector for the element you want. Your original xpath is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is issue about wrong locator `xpath`. Although in given Html there is no element with `ID` as `root` but it seems there can be any parent node with `ID` as `root` Please try with given xpath based on provided html. Hope it will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Endereço de e-mail']");
```

Comment: Don't work:  InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@placeholder=‘Endereço de e-mail’] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@placeholder=‘Endereço de e-mail’]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Those quotation characters are invalid. You should use `'` and `"` instead of `”` and `‘`.

Comment: Yes, I am typing with mobile keypad